# Restriction of rational functions to closed subvarieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes, affine-varieties

I'm confused about a basic point regarding the definition of the ring of regular functions on a closed subvariety. Let $X=\text{Spec}(A)$ be an affine variety (I'm thinking of varieties as integral, separated schemes of finite over an algebraically closed field but I don't think it matters here).  Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal in A; we have a closed subscheme $Y=\text{Spec}(A/\mathfrak{p})\cong V(\mathfrak{p})\subset X$. Therefore the regular functions on $Y$ are the restrictions of regular functions on $X$, given by the quotient map $A\to A/\mathfrak{p}$. In particular I'm thinking about $A = \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, with $\mathfrak{p} = (f)$ for some irreducible polynomial $f$, so the regular functions on $V(f)$ are just polynomials in $x$ and $y$, identified if they agree on $V(f)$.

However, on an open set $U\subset X$, there are additional regular functions other than the restrictions of regular functions on $X$; in particular, we allow rational functions with poles outside $U$. For concreteness, let $h\in A$ be irreducible and suppose that $U=D(h)$, so we have the distinguished inclusion $U\cong \text{Spec}(A_h)\hookrightarrow \text{Spec}(A)$. The regular functions on $U$ then look like $\frac{g(x,y)}{h(x,y)^n}$ for $g\in A$ and $n\geq 0$.

**Question:**
So what happens if $Y\subset U \subset X$? (That is, $V(f)\cap V(h)=\emptyset$.) Thinking of $Y$ as a closed subvariety of $U$, its regular functions are restrictions of regular functions on $U$ (and thus rational functions on $X$), so they are elements of $A_h/(f)$. It's not clear to me how to show in general (if it's even true!) that $A_h/(f)\cong A/(f)$, and so these are in fact the same scheme structure on $Y$.

I suspect that these should in fact be the same structure, and so any rational function like $\frac{g(x,y)}{h(x,y)^n}$ restricted to $V(f)$ should be the same as the restriction of some polynomial $q(x,y)$ to $V(f)$ (again, assuming that $h$ vanishes nowhere on $V(f)$). The only cases that I can come up in $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^2$ of two nonintersecting hypersurfaces are two parallel lines, and there it is clear that, if $f=0$ and $h=0$ define these lines, then $h$ is constant on $V(f)$ so these rational functions agree with polynomials. But I have no idea how one would deal with this in general cases where the intersections or lack thereof are much less obvious.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The idea is that “localizations commute with quotients” so you’ll get the same ring of regular functions either way. I’m traveling so can’t elaborate but hopefully someone else can or you figure it out.

Comment: Ah thanks! That helps. So I guess we want to use $A_h/(f)\cong (A/(f))_h$, and then show that $(A/(f))_h\cong A/(f)$ by showing that $h$ is invertible in $A/(f)$ already. This makes sense intuitively since $h$ has no zeros in $V(f)$. Maybe more formally, since $h$ doesn't vanish at any point in $V(f)$, that means that $h$ is not contained in any maximal ideal of $A/(f)$. Therefore $h$ is invertible. But would this run into trouble with nonreduced schemes, where we aren't supposed to think of regular functions as being determined by values on points?

Comment: You’ve got it. What’s the issue with non reduced schemes here?

Comment: Nevermind about that—I realized I was confusing my argument here (a function is *nonzero* at closed points, and thus doesn't belong to a maximal ideal and is invertible) with the opposite (a function which "evaluates" to 0 at closed points but it itself nonzero). I thought a bit about $\text{Spec}(k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2))$ and I think I've resolved my confusion.

Comment: Great, if you want to gather your thoughts together and answer your own question, I’ll upvote you!

Answer (score 2):

These two rings are in fact the same, so we can consider the subvariety $Y$ directly in $X$, or $Y$ in $U$ in $X$, and and the resulting structure sheaf is the same. Note that $h$ is already invertible in $A/(f)$: since $h$ doesn't vanish at any point of $V(f)$, this mean it isn't contained in any maximal ideal of $A/(f)$, so it must be a unit. Therefore $(A/(f))_h = A/(f)$. Now we use the fact that localization commutes with quotients, so $A_h/(f)\cong (A/(f))_h$. Putting these facts together, we have $A_h/(f)\cong A/(f)$. Therefore the regular functions are in fact the same.